# BigQuery , cache hit from metadata Query always return false when used in a group by statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I use this Query to check BigQuery usage

```
SELECT
  job_id,
  user_email,
  xx.project_id,
  query,
  creation_time,
  cache_hit,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time,start_time,MILLISECOND)/1000 AS duration,
  SUM(total_bytes_processed/1000000000) AS GB,
  SUM(total_bytes_billed/1000000000) AS GB_billed,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(authorTable.table_id), '--') AS base_table,
FROM
  `region-asia-northeast1`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT xx
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(referenced_tables) AS authorTable
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7
```

when I remove the cross join cache_hit return correct results ( false and true), but when I added it back, all cache hit became false ?

Answer (score 1):

I opened a bug report and the solution was to replace cross join by left join